# jQuery form submit preventing default action and then submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am overriding a html form's submit event using jQuery:

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

`event.preventDefault()` to temporarily prevent the actual form post. Howerver after I do some async validation I wish to force post submit the form again:

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    asyncValidationHere(function(valid) {
        if(!valid) { return; }

        // Turn off the custom form submit event handler now since valid
        $('#contact-form').off('submit');

        // Submit (do the actual form post)
        $('#contact-form').submit();
    });
});
```

Howerver I am not seeing the form ever posting. It seems calling `$('#contact-form').off('submit')` and then trying to submit `$('#contact-form').submit()` does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your `asyncValidationHere` callback getting called? If so, is `valid` false-y or truth-y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#contact-form').on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var that = this; // that is the form

    asyncValidationHere(function(valid) {
        if(!valid) { return; }

        $(that).off("submit"); // to guarante the function won't be invoked

        that.submit(); // submit the form
    });
});
```

**Note:** `that.submit();` (not to be confused with `jQuery.submit`) is called on the node (the form), it submits the form (here is the docs on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)).

Comment: calling `submit()` puts you back to the start of my custom handler function which is not what I want. I want to just submit at this point without going back into the submit function handler.

Comment: @Justin No! The submit is called on the Node element not on the jQuery object. It's actually submitting not trigerring the event

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - that's wrong. Calling `submit` on the node will still fire the event handler attached using jQuery. Why wouldn't it?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir touché. However, how is this code any different than the OP's code?

Comment: Almost, had to click the actual submit button twice though removing `$('#contact-form').off('submit')` and calling `that.submit()`. That is not a solution unfortunately.

Comment: @Adam I think I'm wrong as the docs sais it's not guaranteed to trigger the event listeners and not for sure.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir the first time through `that.submit` is not a function JavaScript error using your method.

Comment: @Justin The first time?? What do you mean?

Comment: When I set a breakpoint right before calling `that.submit()` in Chrome and console `that` I see the entire form object, but `submit()` does not exists on it.

Comment: @Justin Could you check if it's a jQuery object or a nodeElement?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Uncaught TypeError: `that.submit` is not a function. Also when `console.log(that)` it is a div element.

Comment: Argggggggg I see my problem. I was setting the `id` to the wrapper div not the form element. Moving the `id="contact-form"` to the actual form worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger the submit event from inside the async function and pass some success flag along with it. Then, inside the handler for the submit event, you could call `preventDefault` based on whether that flag is present. Something like:

```
$('#contact-form').submit(function(event) {

    if (!event.data.valid) {

        event.preventDefault();

        asyncValidationHere(function(valid) {
            if(!valid) { return; }

            // Submit (do the actual form post)
            $('#contact-form').trigger('submit', {valid: true});
        });
    }
});
```